# SSIS Package Configuration Wizard Screen CutOff

Tags: ssis

When I go to the package configuration wizard the configuration filter dialog box is cutoff, has anyone solved this?

[image: Text here]

Resizing window just kept that dialog box cut off

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can resize just fine using the lower right corner sash to change the window.

[image]

An alternative that always works with windows forms is the Tab key as that'll navigate you to the items, even if they're offscreen.

At one point, VS seemed to have rendering issues with the adjust visual experience checkbox and the consensus a decade back was to uncheck that if it was acting "weird." It's been some time since I've had to fiddle with that setting though so the issue seems to have been resolved.

[image]

That's VS 2017 in my screenshots. The corner sash exists on VS 2015 as well. Beyond that, I'd need to go to archives or install current VS editions to explore. As to simulating the drop down arrow selector, holding left Alt key down and hitting the down arrow brings up those selectors.

I think I managed to navigate the entire sequence of adding a configuration without using a mouse in my little video here (although I tried really hard at the end).

[image]

Comment: thanks for the answer but I dont have the corner sash in my window. I also tried going to the visual experience and unchecking it but not luck so far its still cutting off the end of that config box.

Comment: I tried the tab as well but I need to dropdown the configuration filter dialog box. If you know of another way to do that?

Comment: What version of VS are you using?

Comment: @NoahWeitzman Updated to answer + added video clip of keyboard navigation

Comment: Awesome man thank you. The alt plus down arrow solved it for me. Appreciate it. Still not sure why the resizing is happening but it is also happening to my colleauge as well in the same env. Thank you for the help!